# Beveled cylinder cutout

Tags: modeling, geometry, subdivision-surface, bevel

Despite being more proficient in Blender than last time, I'm still struggling with round shapes. Currently I'm working on a small part of a model - a fluid intake. However, I can't seem to create a beveled cutout without breaking the round shape of the base cylinder.
Leaving the edges (see picture) unbeveled isn't an option either, as it will leave the hole as an deformed blob.

How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems hard to do it with a 16 vertices cylinder and with *Bevel* modifier. But here is a hand-made topology on a 32 vertices cylinder that seems to works:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Blender 2.80]  I made an object similar to yours and discovered that applying a bevel to the edges "did" distort the walls of the cylinder when "all" surrounding edges were selected at once.  So I tried to apply the bevel to the edges in stages.

First I beveled the 2 bottom edges (.05 amount), then just the sides and lastly the top edges and it worked... with just one division bevel.  I tried it again with a second window (same staged process).  This time I applied 2 bevel divisions and found that the corners were not well done.  But, with some manual refacing it worked.  It wasn't elegant, but it worked.

This may or may not work for your needs.  And, I hope this is what you were referring to?

[image]